# How to intersect three tables with condition using MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I had 3 tables

```
1.usertb

email     funcarea

2.professiontb

email     experience

3.generalinfo

email     location
```

I want to combine these three tables using the field **email** with 3 conditions like **funarea** = 2 and **experience** >=3 and **location** = 'Sydney'

Since I'm a beginner to SQL, I am eager to know how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.email,funarea,experience,location  from usertb a
left join professiontb b
on a.email = b.email
left join generalinfo c
on  a.email = c.email
where
funarea = 2 and experience >=3 and location = 'Sydney'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have at least one entry in each table:

(blunt and stupid but it works)

```
SELECT * 
FROM usertb, professiontb, generalinfo 
WHERE usertb.email=professiontb.email AND professiontb.email=generalinfo.email AND usertb.funcarea=2 AND professiontb.experience>=3 AND generalinfo.location='Sydney';
```

If you don't have one entry in each table, my advice would be to use the LEFT JOIN statement.

```
SELECT * FROM usertb WHERE usertb.funcarea=2
LEFT JOIN professiontb ON(usertb.email=professiontb.email AND professiontb.experience>=3)
LEFT JOIN generalinfo ON(usertb.email=generalinfo.email AND generalinfo.location='Sydney');
```

As is, you should get all the rows from usertb, even if there is some missing ones in the other tables.